# Different MD5 hash when calculating checksum

Tags: hash, md5, liquibase, checksum

I'm trying to follow this article about calculating MD5 hash for the given scenario.

- Article: https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/maintenance/calculate-checksum.html
- Input value: `changelog.oracle.sql::myID_123::Steve`
- MD5 Output: `8:42b8af7ffb26b44a2716b330d78b90d5`

I tried to get the same hash by using multiple MD5 calculators I found on Google but got always a different hash. (`c4b284f3b4b3e36511f8a523bb75ff0d`)

My question is why is this the case?

Comment: I doubt that the string `changelog.oracle.sql::myID_123::Steve` itself is what hashed but rather the *contents* of the changelog file whose name is `changelog.oracle.sql` along with the id and author name. So you can't reproduce the example because you don't know the content of their changelog file.

Comment: That makes sense! Please provide it as an update and I'll accept it. Thank you.

Comment: I'm just guessing, I don't know for a fact what that tool does. Somebody who is reasonably certain can provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are getting the same hash as the example in the documentation, have you tried to create your own changelog file and then execute the command again?

Note: Enter the name of your changelog, id, and author name that you want to use in place of **changelog.oracle.sql, myID_123, and Steve**. If you use the .sql file, include your database type in place of oracle.